3 days: Avraham's journey vs. Israelite's "journey"
Are there any sources connecting the 3 days Avraham walked to Har Hamoria (Bereshit 22:4) in the test of the Akeda, to the "3 days journey into the desert" Moshe asked King Pharaoh to grant the Israelites (Shemot 3:18)?
Anyone fancy suggesting their own idea?

There's also וַיָּ֗שֶׂם דֶּ֚רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֔ים בֵּינ֖וֹ וּבֵ֣ין יַעֲקֹ֑ב and וַיֵּלְכ֧וּ שְׁלֹֽשֶׁת־יָמִ֛ים בַּמִּדְבָּ֖ר וְלֹא־מָ֥צְאוּ מָֽיִם and וַיִּסְעוּ֙ מֵהַ֣ר יְהוָ֔ה דֶּ֖רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֑ים וַאֲר֨וֹן בְּרִית־יְהוָ֜ה נֹסֵ֣עַ לִפְנֵיהֶ֗ם דֶּ֚רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֔ים לָת֥וּר לָהֶ֖ם מְנוּחָֽה:
and ונינוה היתה עיר גדולה לאלהים מהלך שלשת ימים and לְכוּ־עֹ֛ד שְׁלֹשָׁ֥ה יָמִ֖ים וְשׁ֣וּבוּ אֵלָ֑י

Not a fancy idea, but considering how few times we find a "four day trip", maybe it's an idiom meaning a few days

@DoubleAA the only limit the question puts on ideas is not how fancy they are, but if the idea-haver fancies answering with them

Actually I think the limit is how fancy the answerer is. I am not particularly fancy, as anyone who knows me will attest.

There is a midrash Bereshis Rabba 56:1 about 3rd day. It does not connect it to 3 days travel in the desert but to 3 days preparation at Mt. Sinai. It could be these are one and the same. https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.56.1?lang=bi
